# Ruby GET request with headers and data?

Tags: ruby, oauth

This is a cUrl command I want to do in Ruby

`curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json' --data 'screen_name=example' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="example", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose`

So far I only know how to GET requests using `Net::HTTP` but these don't have headers and data like the cUrl command above.

It would be great if someone could tell me how to GET in Ruby with headers and data.

Comment: this? [take a look at set headers part in ruby doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-Setting+Headers)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't mind using additional GEMS, try [UniRest](http://unirest.io/ruby.html)

Comment: Just linking to a library is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, and providing code using the library to do so makes for a better answer. See: [**How can I link to an external resource in a community-friendly way?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way)